# How to update a SVG-Image without seeing a "blinking"

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I have a SVG-Image, now, when there is an update, the Server sends me the update image, and I want to reload the image in the Browser without seeing a blinking (white space instead of the image for like 100ms).

**My first approach:**

```
$("#svg").html(newSVG); // With blinking
```

**My second approach:**

Loading the updated SVG in Frame2, then put it in Frame1. Still with the blinking.

```
// Load SVG in frame2
$("#svg .frame2").hide().html(content).delay(500).show();

// Overwrite frame1 content  with frame2 content
$("#svg .frame1").delay(500).hide().html(content).delay(500).show();

// Remove frame2 content
$("#svg .frame2").hide().html("").show();
```

Is there any way to to in in a clean way, so the user dont sees a white, empty image for a short time? I can work with jQuery and AngularJS.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Load the image already when the document is being called. The blink you see if probably from loading the image. So if you "download" the image before it is shown it will not blink anymore :)

Comment: What does `newSVG` look like?

Answer (score 3):

**At the lowest levels of graphics programming, they use a trick called double-buffering to update images without flickering**. The idea is that you have a *display driver* somewhere, that you can tell to draw images stored in some region of your memory.

**The intuitive way to handle graphics in this case is to simply do all your drawing into that one region. But with double-buffering, you use *two* regions**: one that holds the last frame you finished, and the other one to draw the frame you're working on. Once you finish drawing , you point the display driver at that region, and draw your next frame in the other region. Because switching back and forth only involves changing one variable (the one that tells the display driver what region to draw), the changeover is very fast. And because the display driver only ever sees finished images, there is no flickering.

**We don't have access to such low-level techniques in the browser, but we can adapt the basic idea behind it**. You do this by loading your image somewhere out of sight, where the user can't see it. Once you're done, you swap out the old image for your new one. One possibility for this might be as follows:

```
// Assume that the new SVG has been loaded into newSVG, like your first example.
var oldSVG = document.getElementById("svg");
oldSVG.parentNode.replaceChild(newSVG, oldSVG);
```

The magic happens in the call to `replaceChild`. **It swaps the old image out for the new one in a single step, so that the browser cannot display any intermediate steps**. This prevents flickering, and potentially saves on performance since the browser only has to reflow once (because an element changed) instead of twice (because an element got removed, and then because an element got added).

Technically, the call to `replaceChild` returns the node that got swapped out, so **you could do this as a one-liner if you were willing to call `document.getElementById` twice for the same element**. But that's wasteful, especially if you'll be doing this a lot, so we use the variable to avoid having to call `document.getElementById` more often than we have to.

Comment: Right at the heart of this answer is the killer adverbial clause "once you're done", which gets no further mention. Unless you can  master "once you're done", the rest of it is pretty pointless.

Answer (score 2):

Put the new frame under the old one (absolute positioning and z-index will help you here), load the new image data into the new frame, in the onload event of the new image move its z-index above the old frame.

Or you could transition the opacity of the old image to 0 on load of the new image and the opacity of the new image to 1.